pandas_ta EMA 50 returning None despite being used with 200 values
I use the following code to access the Binance API, pull the last 200 klines for BTC/USDT and then attempt to produce the EMA 50 as a column in a dataframe:
client = Client('PUBLIC_KEY', 'PRIVATE_KEY')
client.API_URL = 'https://testnet.binance.vision/api'
#obtain historical data for indicator calculation
klines = client.get_historical_klines('BTCUSDT', '1d', limit=200)
klines = np.array(klines)
#convert bars to df
df = pd.DataFrame(klines.reshape(-1,12),dtype=float, columns = ('Open Time',
                                                                'Open',
                                                                'High',
                                                                'Low',
                                                                'Close',
                                                                'Volume',
                                                                'Close time',
                                                                'Quote asset volume',
                                                                'Number of trades',
                                                                'Taker buy base asset volume',
                                                                'Taker buy quote asset volume',
                                                                'Ignore'))

df['Open Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Open Time'], unit='ms')
#run indicators
df['ema50'] =  ta.ema(df['Close'], length=50)

Despite having more than enough values to calculate the EMA, I am getting all None values in the resulting dataframe column. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I realized upon inspecting my dataframe index that the binance testnet only provides up to 20 historical klines regardless of the size of the request. By switching to the regular binance API I was able to get the data I needed.
